# Error while plotting using the plotly library in python?

Tags: python, plotly

## Online sales by store

```
store_daily_sales_sc = list()
for store in store_daily_sales['store'].unique():
      curr_store_sales =              store_daily_sales[store_daily_sales['store']==store]
     store_daily_sales_sc.append(
             go.Scatter(curr_store_sales['date'],
             curr_store_sales['sales'],
             name = f'Store {store}'
            )
    )

 layout = go.Layout(title = 'Store Daily Sales',
              xaxis = dict(title = 'Date'),
              yaxis = dict(title = 'Sales')
              )

  iplot(go.Figure(store_daily_sales_sc,layout))
```

## Error

ValueError: The first argument to the plotly.graph_objs.Scatter
constructor must be a dict or
an instance of :class:`plotly.graph_objs.Scatter`

Can anybody explain why do we need a dictionary while making plots using plotly?. Also, why plotly is throwing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a Scatter trace, you need to pass the data as a dictionary. But you're passing individual arguments instead of a dictionary!

Check the [Docs](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/).

You need to pass the x and y axis as key-value pairs, just like this:

```
store_daily_sales_sc = []

for store in store_daily_sales['store'].unique():
    curr_store_sales = store_daily_sales[store_daily_sales['store'] == store]
    store_daily_sales_sc.append(
        go.Scatter(
            x=curr_store_sales['date'],  # here
            y=curr_store_sales['sales'],  # and here
            name=f'Store {store}'
        )
    )

layout = go.Layout(
    title='Store Daily Sales',
    xaxis=dict(title='Date'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Sales')
)

iplot(go.Figure(store_daily_sales_sc, layout))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Nova. I completely forgot to mention x and y, and thought it would work the same as other plots in Matplotlib.  I read the documentation and found out where was the error.